# create an instance of class in python 2.7

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, instance

I wrote a code:

```
class NewsStory(object):
    def __init__(self, guid, title, subject, summary, link):
        NewsStory.guid = guid
        NewsStory.title = title
        NewsStory.subject = subject
        NewsStory.summary = summary
        NewsStory.link = link

    def getGuid(self):
        return self.guid

    def getTitle(self):
        return self.title

    def getSubject(self):
        return self.subject

    def getSummary(self):
        return self.summary

    def getLink(self):
        return self.link
```

When I added an instance as:

```
test = NewsStory('foo', 'myTitle', 'mySubject', 'some long summary', 'www.example.com')
```

`print test.getGuid()` gives me `foo`, which is correct. However, if I continuously created two instances:

```
test = NewsStory('foo', 'myTitle', 'mySubject', 'some long summary', 'www.example.com')
test1 = NewsStory('foo1', 'myTitle1', 'mySubject1', 'some long summary1', 'www.example1.com')
```

both `print test.getGuid()` and `print test1.getGuid()` gave me `foo1` but no `foo`. Why does it happen? And is there a method that I can modify my class definition or functions inside the class to avoid the new created instance overwriting the old one?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to make those variables in your `__init__` function *instance* variables instead of *class* variables.

Instance variables look like this:

```
self.guid = guid
```

Class variables look like this:

```
NewsStory.guid = guid
```

Class variables are the same for all members of the class, but instance variables are unique to that instance of the class.

Answer (score 1):

The `__init__` method is called after an instance of the class is created. The first argument, called `self` by convention, is the instance of the class. `NewsStory` is the class itself.

In your code, you're creating class variables. You want instance variables:

```
self.guid = guid
```

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying class variables, which are **common to all the objects**. What you should do is to create those variables in the object, like this

```
    self.guid = guid
    self.title = title
    self.subject = subject
    self.summary = summary
    self.link = link
```